# Posting a file to a controller action in Sitecore

Tags: mvc-forms

I want to post a file to a controller/action in my Sitecore project via a "file" input tag.

```html
<input value="choose file" type="file" id="bulk-upload">
```

I see examples, similar to below, online using forms. Is there a better/other way to do this?

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm ("file", "upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: This is a pretty standard way. Is it causing problems for you? What are you looking to improve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In de `HttpPost` action method, capture your file by using a model object as parameter that has a property of the type `HttpPostedFileBase` with the same name as your input file field.

```cs
// The model
public class MyModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile { get; set; }
}

// The action method
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    var file = model.UploadedFile;
}
```

In the view you posted, only the `name` attribute is missing to comply with this example code.

```cs
<input value="choose file" type="file" id="bulk-upload" name="UploadedFile">
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP asked if there are other better ways to post a file to a controller action. What you have written in your answer is the same way he's already using, isn't it?